# I accidentally deleted my files while using git, need some help recovering

Tags: git, github

I was trying to upload a project to a new git repository and I was receiving an error over and over and nothing I tried could fix it. So I decided, maybe like an idiot, to delete the .git folder. Well, that didn't fix the error so I decided to copy my files to a new directory and initialize git from there.

Well, it worked! however, all of my files were deleted. What I don't understand is my project had about 10 vue files in it and a few other assets.

When I copied my other files over to the new folder, I commited and pushed to my new repository without error. All good - however, when checking the repository - it appears that it was just a blank vue project... Now I can't find my original project, each file contained about 300 or so lines of code.

Here's what I have: I have my original directory and the .git folder there. That folder is full of objects, (00, 0b, 0d, 0e, 01, 1a, etc...). The folder now only has the .git folder in it. Is there any way to recover these files based on only have the .git folder from before?

Comment: What does `git status` in the original directory show? The files you’re looking for as deleted? If so (and nothing else), `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Comment: @Ry- here is what git status returns "On branch master

No commits yet

nothing to commit (create/copy files and use "git add" to track)"

the folder is empty and git reset --hard HEAD returns "fatal: ambiguous argument 'HEAD': unknown revision or path not in the working tree."

Comment: If you have objects, there must be some commits in there. Try `git branch -a` and maybe `git log --all` to see if you can identify commits you could go back to that might contain your code. Also potentially helpful: `git reflog`, again, to find a commit your could use with `git reset --hard <commit>`.

Comment: Which `.git` directory did you delete? Do you have the original `.git` directory?

Comment: Yes, I have the original but I can't get anything to work.

Comment: Can you tell us what `git reflog` and `git log --all` show? If you can't get anything to work, can you tell us what you did try and what happened in each case?

Answer (score 0):

You can recover your project only if you have original .git folder before creating new repository. With original .git folder you can use options of `git reset` or `git reflog`. If you are not able to find original .git folder then you cannot recover your files because .git folder is "the magic wand" which makes a normal project a "the git project" so now without .git its just a normal directory.